# What is the template file for topic layouts in bbPress?

Tags: themes, templates, bbpress

The theme I'm using edits the Topic layout in such a way that the role is not being displayed anymore. I'd like to revert those changes in the theme editor, but I can't seem to find the template file for the bbPress topic layout.

Could anyone tell me where to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line #45 of `loop-single-reply.php` ([Source)](http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/templates/default/bbpress/loop-single-reply.php#L45)

```
<?php bbp_reply_author_link( array( 'sep' => '<br />', 'show_role' => true ) ); ?>
```

See Also:
http://codex.bbpress.org/bbp_reply_author_link/ http://codex.bbpress.org/bbp_topic_author_link/